# ftp batch file script

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, ftp

Hoping someone can guide me / help me.

The issue, I have 2 servers one running a Ubuntu which has a website for clients to login and download / view reports. The other is a windows server 2012 R2 which creates / stores the reports. I need to move the files from the windows to the Ubuntu server so clients can view. The data is large currently 7gb and growing at 3 gb a year.

I need a batch file to connect using ftp and then copy the folder to a local folder. However it only needs to copy those files which have modified.

I have only ever written one batch file and I cant seem to find any ftp batch scripts which only copies modifed files.

Your my last resort as I cant seem to find a coder who knows batch script (its a dieing art). I have never used powershell so would not know where to start here.

Any help or advice please let me know.

Thanks
John

Comment: i think rsync may be your friend

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/287489/download-only-new-files-from-ftp-using-wget-curl

Comment: Hi thanks for your ideas. I had a look and both need me to do sometihng I'm not familar with so will let you know how I get on.

Comment: I have come across winscp program. This should securoy mange the transfer but still not sure about the script part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with PowerShell with [winscp](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell#example). Exemple :

```
try
{
# Load WinSCP .NET assembly
Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"

# Setup session options
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
    HostName = "example.com"
    UserName = "user"
    Password = "mypassword"
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"
}

$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

try
{
    # Connect
    $session.Open($sessionOptions)

    # Upload files
    $transferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions
    $transferOptions.TransferMode = [WinSCP.TransferMode]::Binary

    $transferResult = $session.PutFiles("d:\toupload\*", "/home/user/", $False, $transferOptions)

    # Throw on any error
    $transferResult.Check()

    # Print results
    foreach ($transfer in $transferResult.Transfers)
    {
        Write-Host ("Upload of {0} succeeded" -f $transfer.FileName)
    }
}
finally
{
    # Disconnect, clean up
    $session.Dispose()
}


    exit 0
}
catch [Exception]
{
    Write-Host ("Error: {0}" -f $_.Exception.Message)
    exit 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a way to do it in PowerShell. It would take files that are older then 31 days and upload them.

```
function FTP-Upload {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$Source_File,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$Target_File,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$Target_Server,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$Target_Username,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$Target_Password
    )

    $FTP = [System.Net.FTPWebRequest]::Create("ftp://$Target_Server/$Target_File")
    $FTP = [System.Net.FTPWebRequest]$FTP
    $FTP.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::UploadFile
    $FTP.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Target_Username,$Target_Password)
    $FTP.UseBinary = $true
    $FTP.UsePassive = $true
    # read in the file to upload as a byte array
    $content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($Source_File)
    $FTP.ContentLength = $content.Length
    # get the request stream, and write the bytes into it
    $rs = $FTP.GetRequestStream()
    $rs.Write($content, 0, $content.Length)
    # be sure to clean up after ourselves
    $rs.Close()
    $rs.Dispose()
}

$Upload_Server = "server.network.tld"
$Upload_Location = "/data/"
$Upload_Username = "ftpuser"
$Upload_Password = "ftppassword"

$Files_To_Upload = Get-ChildItem E:\Path\To\Files -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.CreationTime -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-31)) -and (!$_.PSIsContainer)}

Foreach ($File in $Files_To_Upload) {
    FTP-Upload -Source_File $File.FullName -Target_File ($Upload_Location + $File.Name) -Target_Server $Upload_Server -Target_Username $Upload_Username -Target_Password $Upload_Password
}
```